# How would I close a modal box using AJAX on complete? - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to close a modal box in my ASP.NET MVC project using the AJAX method complete.

The following method closes the box, but the page underneath becomes unclickable after the modal box has closed.

```
complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    $('#modalBox').collapse();
},
```

What would the correct implementation of this be?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you using any frameworks like bootstrap or any plugins, if yes then `hide` is not a good approach. because every plugin will have some methods to close or open modal , you can use them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide with this:

```
$('#modalBox').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You also close this type.

```
$('#modalBox').model('hide');
```